# How to offer custom sub-domains for SAAS Application

Tags: php, .htaccess, saas, cname

How do i offer Basecamp/SAAS App like sub domains to clients?

For example, my website URL is `http://www.example.com` whenever the user signup i want to offer them url like `http://company.example.com` which should load files/contents from `/app` directory of the website.

And later i want them to choose their own domain/sub-domain via CNAME, so that they can have URL like `http://clients.mywebsite.com`

I want to do this in Pure PHP and .HTACCESS and offcourse everything happens automatically.

And i want to keep URL structure same.., that is `http://company.example.com/login`, `http://company.example.com/accounts`, `http://company.example.com/files/style.css` though these files are located inside `/app` directory i want them to be accessed like this.

I can handle all PHP functions, i need help with .htaccess codes and how to go about CNAME.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make sure DNS resolves all subdomains by including following in domain's zone:

```
*.example.com. 14400 IN A HereBeIP
```

Next, configure web server to recognize all incoming requests, for Apache, you need to add following to VirtualHost:

```
ServerAlias *.example.com
```

That's it. The only thing remaining is the logic in the code, you need to check host name to see whether a request was done to example.com or foo.example.com.

**Updated** with more details.

So, assuming your files are in `/path/to/files/app`, you need to configure virtual host like this:

```
<VirtualHost>
    SeverName example.com
    ServerAlias *.example.com
    DocumentRoot /path/to/files/app
    # plus what else is needed
</VirtualHost>
```

This way all requests will resolve to `/app` directory. To test it, apply above DNS configuration or simply add the domains you want tested into your `hosts` file, `/etc/hosts` on Linux or `c:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` on Windows.

Comment: How do i do this with .HTACCESS, i mean whenever a request is sent (http://company.example.com) php will display page accordingly, but i want to keep the URL structure same.

Comment: in short, you cant with just .HTACCESS

Comment: As Dagon said, you can't do it with .htaccess. Make sure to apply above settings, what's left is just Apache configuration to point to the same structure.

Comment: if your on a shared hosting account your probably our of luck, get a dedicated server instead.

Comment: For now i am using it on Development server, i will use Dedicated server later on, what i want to know is how will i get the files from /app directory when a sub domain is visited/opened